# Does a data structure like this exist?

Tags: sorting, data-structures, functional-programming

I'm searching for a data structure that can be sorted as fast as a plain list and which should allow to remove elements in the following way. Let's say we have a list like this:

```
[{2,[1]},
 {6,[2,1]},
 {-4,[3,2,1]},
 {-2,[4,3,2,1]},
 {-4,[5,4,3,2,1]},
 {4,[2]},
 {-6,[3,2]},
 {-4,[4,3,2]},
 {-6,[5,4,3,2]},
 {-10,[3]},
 {18,[4,3]},
 {-10,[5,4,3]},
 {2,[4]},
 {0,[5,4]},
 {-2,[5]}]
```

i.e. a **list containing tuples** (this is Erlang syntax). Each tuple contains **a number**, and a **list which includes the members of a list used to compute previous number**. What I want to do with the list is the following. First, **sort** it, then **take the head** of the list, and finally ***clean*** the list. With ***clean* I mean to remove all the elements from the tail that contain elements that are in the head**, or, in other words, all the elements from the tail which intersection with head is not empty. For example, after sorting the head is `{18,[4,3]}`. Next step is removing all the elements of the list that contain `4` or `3`, i.e. the resulting list should be this one:

```
[{6,[2,1]},
 {4,[2]},
 {2,[1]},
 {-2,[5]}]
```

The process follows by taking the new head and cleaning again till the whole list is consumed. Note that if the the clean process preserves the order, there is no need to resorting the list each iteration.

The **bottleneck here is the clean process**. I would need some structure which allows me to do the cleaning in a faster way than now.

**Does anyone know some structure that allows to do this in an efficient way without losing the order or at least allowing fast sorting?**

Comment: You would need some sort of supporting index structure to create non-linear lookup efficiency for you. i.e. keep track of which nodes have which integer values.

You would then need to account for the overhead of maintaining the supporting index structure in your cost formulation.

Comment: What exactly is "efficient"? What is "fast sorting"? Is a standard list not sufficient? What operations do you need and with what average complexities?

Comment: It's not really clear whether you are talking about the outer list, the inner lists, or the structure as a whole.

Comment: @Bergi With efficient I mean logN or N. Fast sorting means same sorting time than a common list. I need sort and delete (las one in the special way described above). I'm talking about the outer list. I would need to replace this list by the _unknown_ data structure. Sorry if it's unclear. I didn't know how to explain the problem.

Comment: A single linked list can be sorted reasonably fast using a small array (26 to 32) pointers to nodes and a bottom up merge sort. [wiki example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation_using_lists) .  Inserting and removing nodes from a single linked list is fast, but searching for a specific value requires a linear pass over the list.

Comment: @SalvadorTamarit: Build, sort, delete and access I would guess, otherwise it's useless? Do you need indexed access, or just iteration? By what do you need to sort, arbitrary data stored in those records? Is there anything special about the inner lists? They seem to be substrings. Also, the deletion complexity will mostly depend on the number of selected elements (3, 4) and the average size of the inner lists, regarding the length of the outer list you'll hardly get better than O(N).

Comment: Maybe instead of answering all these questions, it would be easier to tell us what problem you are solving, not how you want your data structure behave.

Comment: @rcgldr I'm using currently Erlang lists, but the problem is more in deleting than in sorting currently. I've edited the explanation of the problem, so maybe now it is clearer. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Bergi I need access to the head. I need to sort them by the first element of the tuples. The second element are substring yes. Delete with O(N) would be nice, but here it is not the case. I've added more text explaining the problem. I hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can get faster than this. Your problem is that you are representing the second tuple members as lists. Searching them is cumbersome and quite unnecessary. They are all contiguous substrings of `5..1`. You could simply represent them as a tuple of indices!

And in fact you don't even need a list with these index tuples. Put them in a two-dimensional array right at the position given by the respective tuple, and you'll get a [triangular array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_array):

```
h\l|  1   2   3   4   5
---+----------------------
 1 |  2
 2 |  6   2
 3 | -4  -6  -10
 4 | -2  -4   18  2
 5 | -4  -10 -10  0  -2
```

Instead of storing the data in a two-dimensional array, you might want to store them in a simple array with some index magic to account for the triangular shape (if your programming language only allows for rectangular two-dimensional arrays), but that doesn't affect complexity.

This is all the structure you need to quickly filter the "list" by simply looking the things up.

Instead of sorting first and getting the head, we simply iterate once through the whole structure to find the *maximum* value and its indices:

```
max_val = 18
max = (4, 3) // the two indices
```

The filter is quite simple. If we don't use lists (`` not (any (substring `contains`) selection) ``) or sets (`isEmpty (intersect substring selection)`) but tuples then it's just `sel.high < substring.low || sel.low > substring.high`. And we don't even need to iterate the whole triangular array, we can simple iterate the higer and the lower triangles:

```
result = []
for (i from 1 until max[1])
    for (j from i until max[1])
        result.push({array[j][i], (j,i)})
for (i from max[0] until 5)
    for (j from i until 5)
        result.push({array[j+1][i+1], (j+1,i+1)})
```

And you've got the elements you need:

```
[{ 2, (1,1)},
 { 6, (2,1)},
 { 4, (2,2)},
 {-2, (5,5)}]
```

Now you only need to sort that and you've got your result.

---

Actually the overall complexity doesn't get better with the triangular array. You still got `O(n)` from building the list and finding the maximum. Whether you filter in `O(n)` by testing against every substring index tuple, or filter in `O(|result|)` by smart selection doesn't matter any more, but you were specifically asking about a fast cleaning step. This still might be beneficial in reality if the data is large, or when you need to do multiple cleanings.
The only thing affecting overall complexity is to sort only the result, not the whole input.

Comment: Yes, doing this I have removed the bottleneck. FIltering in this way is much more faster. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if your original data structure can be seen as an adjacency list for a directed graph? E.g;

```
{2,[1]},
{6,[2,1]}
```

means you have these nodes and edges;

```
node 2 => node 1
node 6 => node 2
node 6 => node 1
```

So your question can be rewritten as;

> If I find a node that links to nodes 4 and 3, what happens to the graph if I delete nodes 4 and 3?

One approach would be to build an adjacency matrix; an NxN bit matrix where every edge is the 1-bit. Your problem now becomes;

> set every bit in the 4-row, and every bit in the 4-column, to zero.

That is, nothing links in or out of this deleted node.

As an optimisation, keep a bit array of length N. The bit is set if the node hasn't been deleted. So if nodes 1, 2, 4, and 5 are 'live' and 3 and 6 are 'deleted', the array looks like

```
[1,1,0,1,1,0]
```

Now to delete '4', you just clear the bit;

```
[1,1,0,0,1,0]
```

When you're done deleting, go through the adjacency matrix, but ignore any edge that's encoded in a row or column with `0` set.

Full example. Lets say you have

```
[ {2, [1,3]},
  {3, [1]},
  {4, [2,3]} ]
```

That's the adjacency matrix

```
  1 2 3 4
1 0 0 0 0  # no entry for 1
2 1 0 1 0  # 2, [1,3]
3 1 0 0 0  # 3, [1]
4 0 1 1 0  # 4, [2,3]
```

and the mask

```
  [1 1 1 1]
```

To delete node 2, you just alter the mask;

```
  [1 0 1 1]
```

Now, to figure out the structure, pseudocode like:

```
rows = []
for r in 1..4:
  if mask[r] == false:
    # this row was deleted
    continue;

  targets = []
  for c in 1..4:
    if mask[c] == true && matrix[r,c]:
      # this node wasn't deleted and was there before
      targets.add(c)

  if (!targets.empty):
    rows.add({ r, targets})
```

Adjacency matrices can get large - it's NxN bits, after all - so this will only better on small, dense matrices, not large, sparse ones.

If this isn't great, you might find that it's easier to google for graph algorithms than invent them yourself :)

Comment: The first number of the tuple is not a node of a graph, so you misunderstood the problem sorry. I've added more text explaining the problem because I've seen that was awfully explained. I hope it can be understood better now :) Thanks anyway for your answer. In any case, I've been thinking in graphs and trees as a way to face this problem, but I was not able to find a solution that has all my requirements.